# The server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, jwt, token

I have register/login page and when user is registering he can upload image, which should be send to server, when server gets data, it should generate token and token should include uploaded file ("data:image/jpeg;base64"), when it generates token, it is very big and i get 431 Status.
Is there any way to fix this issue?

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this._id, isAdmin: this.isAdmin, name: this.name, image: this.image, email: this.email }, 'jwtPrivateKey');
    return token;
}
```

Comment: What kind of information do you include in your JWT? Can you update your question to provide some code?

Comment: I am including _id, isAdmin (boolean), name and image

Comment: To debug this try to look into the headers being sent by the servers, and also into the size of the token. Do not include too many information in your JWT.

Comment: *Is there any way to fix this issue?* - yes, don't put a picture into the token.